# How to add comments on Python Django posts with logged in username?

Tags: python, django

Please let me know that where i am making mistake?
**views.py**

```
class AddComment(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'comment.html'

    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.name = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs\['pk'\]
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Are these forms written correctly?
**forms.py**
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = Comment
fields = ('body', )

```
        widgets = {
            # 'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Should I make any changes in models?
**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,
                             related_name='comments',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField(max_length=240)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.post.title, self.name)
```

This is comment section for letting user to comment on post with showing its own name?
**comments.html**

```
{% if not object.comments.all %}
    <p>No comments yet...</p>
    <a href="{% url 'comment' object.pk %}">Add one</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'comment' object.pk %}">Add Comment</a>
    <br><br>
    {% for comment in object.comments.all %}
    <strong>{{ comment.name }} </strong> - <small>{{ comment.date_added }}</small>
    <br>
    {{ comment.body }}
    <br><br>
    <hr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Here is the urls of AddComment class view.
**urls.py**

```
path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', AddComment.as_view(), name='comment'),][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not state clearly what has gone wrong with your code. I would like to give some suggestions. First of all,

```
{% for comment in object.comments.all %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

You are putting this block of code inside {% if not object.comments.all %}...{% endif %} so it will not show on template if the comment section is not empty.

Also, this link:

```
<a href="{% url 'comment' object.pk %}">Add Comment</a>
```

should open a [Django template form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/), where user can actually fill in the comment. After that, on POST request of the form, it will send comment data to the URL you put in *action* param of the form, as below:

```
<form action="{% url 'comment' post.pk %}" method="post">
[Comment code here]
</form>
```

which will link to this URL you provided:

```
path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', AddComment.as_view(), name='comment'),]
```

It will be better if you can provide your code in views.py as well to make it easier to track down where it goes wrong.

Comment: Thank your for your suggestions. but Views.py file is already given at the top.